# I can't seem to put the value of a variable with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

my js script :

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); 
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;


document.getElementById("heure").innerHTML = today;
```

my html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
   <script src="../js/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <p>
       Il est :    <span id="heure"></span>
   </p>
   <p>
       et vous etes actuellement sur mon site, quel honneur.
   </p>
</body>
</html>
```

the alert to test the javascript file work, document.write(today) work, realy i dont understand...

Comment: Try putting the `<script>` tag at the end of `body`

Comment: Oh my god, seriously is that thak so much !

Comment: You can also wrap the js in a `window.onload`

Comment: It looks like you're not aware of debugging capabilities of your browser. Hit F12 and stop alerting and writing to document. You can also see the error messages in the console, and DevTools contain a lot of other useful features for degbugging your code.

Comment: Window.onload did not work to

Comment: Yes, i will use the debugging, i'm a begginer ^^

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make JavaScript execute after page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/how-to-make-javascript-execute-after-page-load)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try using script tag at the end of body**, most probably the issue here is that, the script is loading before DOM, because of which it cannot recognise span tag

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the element by ID before it is initiated.
Call the script which has getelementbyID after the span or the body tags.